# Tried to undo git commit with reset --mixed but don't see any changes

Tags: git

I committed to git from my local branch, and belatedly realized that some files should't be committed were went with it. To undo it,I did git 'reset --mixed', I was expecting to see the pre-commit list when I did a git-status. But it does not show me any staged changes. I only see untracked files that is not the complete list of files pre-commit. Can someone please explain what needs to be done to go to my pre-commit state, so I can add selected files and re-commit.

To be clear, when I do a git status now it says no changes added to commit, but I don't see my modified files either in staging or untracked area.

Comment: Was it `git reset --mixed` or `git reset HEAD^ --mixed`? The latter is the expected one.

Comment: git reset --mixed I'm afraid.

Comment: `git reset` needs a commit. If it is omitted, it implies HEAD. Since the current branch is already on HEAD, `git reset HEAD --mixed` has no effect. So try `git reset HEAD^`. `--mixed` can be omitted because it's the default option.

Comment: @ElpieKay thank you! that makes sense now. It worked.